# Migrated question from SU about Google Calendar rejection "is wrong" (IMHO of course)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

The question [How can I embed a Google calendar with Material Design?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/114651/88163) originally was posted on SU then migrated to Web Applications the rejected with the following reason:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close
>   gave this specific reason:
>
> "It is a question about creating/developing a web application." –
>   jonsca

I think that the rejection was made in effect immediately because was made by a diamond moderator and now it's not possible to edit or comment on the copy of the question on this site but in SU is still on-hold as off-topic.

IMHO the question is on-topic on Web Applications because Google Calendar has a tool for end-users to customize the calendar embedding code and there is an official help article about this topic -> [Add a Google calendar to your website](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en)

Is it possible to revert the "migration rejection"?

Comment: Definitely possible that I got this one wrong.  I was not aware of the tool.  To me, it looked like a web development question that only peripherally related to Google Calendar.  I'll wait and see if anyone weighs in, and we can get it back if need be.

Comment: I tend to agree with Ruben on this one. I can't vote to re-open, however, probably since it's a rejected migration.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is probably to delete the Super User post and repost here afresh.

Getting the current question back would either require the Super User mods to reopen and then re-migrate the question or for one of us mods to clear the migration history at this end and reopen the question.

It will be far easier for the OP to delete the Super User version and repost. I've left a comment to that effect on the Super User version.